# iOS 13 UserDefaults: app crash on start on some devices

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, userdefaults

App crashes on iOS 13 on some devices on launching. The app is in production and I have seen this problem in Xcode Organizer Crashes. I cannot reproduce this problem neither on simulator or any of physical devices.

I suppose it has something to do with the localization. I use 'AppleLanguages' key and I save chosen language as an array. I save language in User Defaults as:

```
static var language: Language {
    get {

        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: isLanguageSelectedKey) {
            if let languageCode = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: appleLanguagesKey)?.first,
                let language = Language(rawValue: languageCode as! String) {
                return language
            } else {

                return Language.someLanguage
            }
        } else {
            return Language.someLanguage
        }

    }

    set {
        guard language != newValue else {
            return
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: appleLanguagesKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        UserDefaults.standard.set([newValue.rawValue], forKey: appleLanguagesKey)

        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
```

Stacktrace I see in Xcode Organizer Crashes is:

```
Last Exception Backtrace (0)
0   (null) in __exceptionPreprocess ()
-------------------------------------------------------
8   (null) in +[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) standardUserDefaults] ()
9   (null) in __45+[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher fetcherUserDefaults]_block_invoke ()
10  (null) in _dispatch_client_callout ()
11  (null) in _dispatch_once_callout ()
12  (null) in +[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher fetcherUserDefaults] ()
13  (null) in +[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher fetchersForBackgroundSessions] ()
14  (null) in +[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher load] ()
15  (null) in load_images ()
-------------------------------------------------------



Thread 1
0   (null) in __pthread_kill ()
-------------------------------------------------------
9   (null) in _dispatch_once_callout ()
10  (null) in +[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher fetcherUserDefaults] ()
11  (null) in +[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher fetchersForBackgroundSessions] ()
12  (null) in +[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher load] ()
13  (null) in load_images ()
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you try without this line `UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: appleLanguagesKey)`

Comment: I don't think that that could have provoked this situation because the 'set 'code block is called after the user has chosen the language and the app crashes before that

Comment: You don't need to remove key before setting it, and also don't use `synchronize`. Apple says "this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used."

Comment: And also you have `languageCode as! String` - are you sure it's a string and not, say, Int?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have everything, so there were some assumptions here that may not be properly addressed:

```
static var language: Language {
get {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: isLanguageSelectedKey),
             let languageCode = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: appleLanguagesKey)?.first as? string,
             let language = Language(rawValue: languageCode) {
                return language
        }
        // No language value found, so return someLanguage
        return Language.someLanguage

    }
set {
    guard language != newValue else {
        return
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: appleLanguagesKey)
    UserDefaults.standard.set([newValue.rawValue], forKey: appleLanguagesKey)
}
```

What was done?

1. The `languageCode` is now safely unwrapped to avoid a forced cast, that can cause a crash
2. The if statement was rewritten to make it more concise and eliminate one scenario that led to the `Language.someLanguage` return
3. I removed the `synchonize()` calls in your setter